Persist Power BI Data source Credentials
I created a REST API that is responsible for updating the data source of the specific report and then refreshing it.
API to update the datasource: https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/Default.UpdateDatasources
API to refresh the dataset:
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes
When I try to refresh the dataset, I get some credentials related error:
The refresh failed for this model. Expand the technical details for more info.Hide details
Data source error:  It looks like scheduled refresh failed because at least one data source is missing credentials. To start the refresh again, go to this dataset's settings page and enter credentials for all data sources.
Cluster URI:    WABI-INDIA-CENTRAL-A-PRIMARY-redirect.analysis.windows.net
Activity ID:    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Request ID: ff70b198-de5a-4572-b36f-78858b062ef3
Time:   2024-12-09 05:52:16Z

Under the Data source credentials section in settings page I get this error:
Failed to test the connection to your data source. Please retry your credentials.Learn more
Settings Page
After this, I have to enter the credentials manually (after every request).
Is there any way to persist this credentials ?

Then why don't you use any c# application to update the credentials?

Which type of data source you created?

I am using an API as an datasource.

can you check this once.

Not working....

You're only required to sign in to a data source the first time you use refresh on that semantic model. Once entered, those credentials are retained with the semantic model.

Yes, it works fine when I sign in. But when I request again, it shows the same error. So I have to sign in and enter the credentials every time.
I found a doc: link.

check this once. Or go to the global permission settings and clear the permissions for that data source.


When your credentials are incorrect while testing the data source, you will get above error. Edit the credentials correctly.

After this, I have to enter the credentials manually (after every request).
Is there any way to persist this credentials ?

Once check your credentials type of data source, if it is Anonymous, change it to Basic, provide the credential and publish the report, wait for some time after the publish, you may get relief from above error. Otherwise, check the permissions of Datasource by going to global permissions as shown below:

According to the MS document
This error can occur when the gateway attempts a test connection, even if the credentials supplied are acceptable and the refresh operation is successful. It happens because when the gateway performs a connection test, it doesn't include any optional parameters during the connection attempt, and some data connectors, (Snowflake, for example) require optional connection parameters in order to connect.
When your refresh is completing properly and you don't experience runtime errors, you can ignore these test connection errors for data sources that require optional parameters. For more information you can refer to the below documents:

https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Power-BI-not-saving-basic-authentication-credentials-during/m-p/358968

Why does PowerBI ask for credentials when refreshi... - Microsoft Fabric Community



I tried the above method but didn't get any solution to the current problem.
Additional Inforamation:
The source of data is an REST API created in Laravel. Can this cause any issues? I am trying to change the source which is API endpoint (some parameters of the API).

check this once.

In my case after change parameters for each one of the sources I could fix this issue. For some reason it started considering fix IP and disabled parameters, I edited it via PBI Desktop, remove the fix IP and add parameters (server and database).
from
= PostgreSQL.Database("111.111.111.111:PORT", db_prod)
to
= PostgreSQL.Database(Server_IP, Database)

